# Documentation for Arduino SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Here](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2412/should-arduino-se-get-a-documentation-section) is a question that is already asked with a similar intension. But i am trying to be more specific.

Let me explain how my question is different. Even-though they are towards the same goal, the linked question seems to be very generic and would invite a wide spectrum of answers. This question explains why we need a documentation for arduino, with example.

FAQ is of course the best thing for beginners. but looking at the bigger picture, just like we have documentation for C#, which is indeed helpful because it is more understandable and generic than the QAs.

The number of questions unnecessarily increase(Not an issue..) if people don't find the exact question(even-though people find similar ones).
just like how i need to ask this question.

Consider a situation where i need to interface some new module to my arduino, i am looking into Arduino SE and find find questions that are related. like `"How to connect my XX module?"`, `"I have tried this code to interface XX module but is not working"` etc. but, a beginner would be more interested in a more `descriptive document which would help him do his job from the beginning, till the end`.

hope i am making some sense.

Comment: +1 You pretty much got it! This is really why I find it great if specific SEs such as Arduino, Pi, (cooking?!?)..... should get documentation. Though we might get more "useless" questions, making some stuff clear is very important. There are really not enough good tutorial out there that can cover many because they are often made by a person or a small group. If all of this community would work togheter to write some great documentation for the Arduino an many popular sensors/modules. It would be very helpful for everybody else

Comment: Also, we frequently get questions about error messages. If we could make a documentation about all of the possible error messages out there, it could really help many users (including me!).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should Arduino SE get a documentation section?](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/2412/should-arduino-se-get-a-documentation-section)

Comment: We could set up a meta page with a list of common errors/questions/etc.

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin thats a great idea...! but does that match a good documentation.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny, What is your actual question?

Comment: @sa_leinad i am requesting a nice documentation portal for arduino. Just like how stack overflow has got one!